# Laravel 5.2 routes without oauth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-5

I would like to ask if how can I implement a routes that can be access without an access_token but has a validation for client_id and client_secret that needs to be existing before I allow the route to be access.

Im using this oauth 2.0 library
https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Basically this is the routes when you have a middleware for access_token:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>"oauth"],function(){
        Route::resource('main_category', 'MainCategoryController');
    });
```

My problem is how can I access the 
`Route::resource('main_category', 'MainCategoryController');`
without an access_token

Comment: Trying to access a route that requires an `access_token` without said token is kinda going against the whole logical implementation isn't it?

Comment: I have a used case that for example that MainCategoryController where it displays all the main category eventhough that user is not logged in. Like in an ecommerce site where all products and categories are displayed.